# Flex DropDownList working weird in mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, air, adobe

I try to use spark DropDownList Controller for flex mobile project but its not working properly. Is there any alternative solution available?

Comment: When you ask questions here please post more information.  Not working properly is the reason for most stack overflow posts (or rather not working how the end user of an API expected) please post the code your using and describe the scenario in more detail, what is your goal where does your program fall short of the goal, what are the specific issues you are seeing, screenshots if explanation is difficult.

Comment: The dropdownlist and combobox aren't for mobile - they're basically useless.  You'll want to pop up a list component for selecting a value.  There are a few out there you can implement or roll  your own.

Answer (score 1):

The Flex Spark DropDownList is not supported on mobile devices.  To get it working requires more than just implementing a mobile skin.  It relates primarily to the differences between mouse input and touch input.

However, we've already done the conversion work for you, so you can use our [Mobile DropDownList](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=21) as part of the Flextras Mobile Component set.  Free developer editions are available for you test out for your own purposes.

---

Earlier in 2013; the Flextras components were open sourced; and you can get the source of the mobile components straight from [GitHub](https://github.com/Flextras/FlextrasComponents/tree/master/mobileComponents).  The Flextras site still distributes binary builds if you don't want to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`<s:List/>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html). As said by @www.Flextras.com, DropDownLists aren't supported on mobile.